# I want to store the text from input in array and shuffle it alphabetically, how it can be done?

Tags: javascript, html

All I want is to get value from input field ,it may be a name, afterwards it should shuffle the alphabets and generate a new single name on every click , most likely it will use onclick event. I am not sure its the right code. Thanks in advance
Like, Ali -> Lia -> ila etc.
Here is my Js and its not working.

```js
function shufflemyinput(){
    names = document.getElementById('y_name').value;
    var namesValue = [];
    namesValue.push(names.value);
    var shuffle = str.split('').sort(function(){
        return 0.5-Math.random()
    }).join('');
    var shuffled = getElementById("result3").innerHTML ="<br>" + shuffle;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" id="y_name">
<a type="button" class="Mylinkbutton btn" onclick="shufflemyinput();">Fetch Name</a>
<h4 id="result3"></h4>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<a type="button"...`?
How about `<input type="button"...`?
Or, simply `<button...`?

Comment: I think you can move the `<br>` from the script and into the HTML (after the button).

Answer (score 0):

If you were running the script you would see the console error: `str` is not defined and `getElementById` is a method of `document`:

```js
function shufflemyinput(){
    names = document.getElementById('y_name').value;
    var namesValue = [];
    namesValue.push(names.value);
    var shuffle = names.split('').sort(function(){
        return 0.5-Math.random()
    }).join('');
    var shuffled = document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML ="<br>" + shuffle;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" id="y_name">
<a type="button" class="Mylinkbutton btn" onclick="shufflemyinput();">Fetch Name</a>
Here it should display the name
<h4 id="result3"></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to an array. Then shuffle it and convert it back to string and show the result.

```js
function shuffle(event){
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  // convet string into an array of characters
  const stringArray = Array.from(username);
  const shuffledArray = stringArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  // convert back array to string
  const result = shuffledArray.join('');
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<button onclick="shuffle(event)">Shuffle</button>
<br>
<span>Result: </span> <span id="result"></span>
```